# Can't build with mozilla-apk-cli without zip/unzip

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to build a packaged open web app with mozilla-apk-cli. But when I try it tells me I need to install unzip and zip from Info-zip. But the Info-zip site is beyond dated and the .msi I ran from there doesn't appear to have done anything. 
I'm on Windows 8.1 64bit. 
How am I expected to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of mozilla-apk-cli. I don't develop on Windows, so I need your help!

1) I'll do some digging, I assumed (wrongly) that Info-zip would install on Windows 8.1 64-bit

2) What is the preferred tool for zip/unzip from the command line on Windows 8.1? Can you point me at it's documentation?

Thanks for your help in improving mozilla-apk-cli.

Also: I've filed https://github.com/mozilla/apk-cli/issues/3

**Update**: [I've documented how to install Info-ZIP](https://github.com/mozilla/apk-cli/blob/master/docs/WINDOWS.md). Thanks to Myk and nmaier.

I've tested this fix on Windows 8.1 and was able to build an APK.

Comment: Sweetness! I got it working I just had to run the .msi in a directory on the PATH. but the install process for it was a bit of an unpleasantexperiance ftp, etc. something like this  https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-zip would be awesome if it were bundled with the mozilla-apk-cli I've never had to use a command line zipper on windows

Comment: oops read your issue you posted, what do you mean "blow up all the known NodeJS libraries."?

Comment: Originally, mozilla-apk-cli did zip and unzip directly using NodeJS code. Unfortunately, I found zip files that would break. I tried many different NodeJS libraries that did zip/unzip but they all broke on at least one of the .zip files from the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Until @Ozten fixes this, you might want to just get some binaries somewhere else, like gnuwin32 ([zip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm), [unzip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm)) and put then somewhere in your [`PATH`](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).